# Confluent Sftp sink connector returns Failed to open new SFTP channel with existing session

Tags: apache-kafka, sftp, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

sftp sink connector returns Failed to open new SFTP channel with existing session

The stack trace of the error is below, we are able to connect to the sftp server using the credentials used by the connector, however this error occurs every time the connector attempts to write to the sftp server:

```html
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:618)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:334)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:235)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to open new SFTP channel with existing session.
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.connection.SftpConnection.newChannelFromSession(SftpConnection.java:108)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.storage.SftpOutputStream.createPath(SftpOutputStream.java:48)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.storage.SftpOutputStream.<init>(SftpOutputStream.java:44)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.storage.SftpSinkStorage.create(SftpSinkStorage.java:87)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.format.csv.CsvRecordWriter.<init>(CsvRecordWriter.java:32)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.format.csv.CsvRecordWriterProvider.getRecordWriter(CsvRecordWriterProvider.java:29)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.format.csv.CsvRecordWriterProvider.getRecordWriter(CsvRecordWriterProvider.java:12)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.TopicPartitionWriter.getWriter(TopicPartitionWriter.java:408)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.TopicPartitionWriter.writeRecord(TopicPartitionWriter.java:454)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.TopicPartitionWriter.checkRotationOrAppend(TopicPartitionWriter.java:250)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.TopicPartitionWriter.writePartitionWhe..
```

Below is the current config for the sftp connector

```js
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connector
metadata:
  name: update-sftp-sink-connector
  namespace: confluent
spec:
  name: update-sftp-sink-connector
  taskMax: 1
  class: io.confluent.connect.sftp.SftpSinkConnector
  configs:
    topics: updates-topic
    file.delim: "."
    sftp.host: "my.host.name"
    sftp.port: "22"
    sftp.username: ${file:/mnt/secrets/connect-connector-secrets/sftp-creds:username}
    sftp.password: ${file:/mnt/secrets/connect-connector-secrets/sftp-creds:password}
    sftp.working.dir: "/updates"
    directory.delim: "/"
    rotate.interval.ms: "120000"
    flush.size: 1
    partition.duration.ms: "120000"
    partitioner.class: io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner
    format.class: io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.format.csv.CsvFormat
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    storage.class: io.confluent.connect.sftp.sink.storage.SftpSinkStorage
    locale: en-GB
    timezone: UTC
    timestamp.extractor: Record
  restartPolicy:
    type: OnFailure
    maxRetry: 10
  connectClusterRef:
    name: connect
    namespace: confluent`
```